Find cusps of $\Gamma_1(p)$, show $\frac{j(\tau)}{j(2\tau)}$ is a modular function of weight $0$ level $\Gamma_1(2)$, which cusps is it holomorphic?
Firstly for notation, let
$$\Gamma_1(p) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \mid a \equiv d \equiv 1 \pmod p, c \equiv 0 \pmod p  \right\},$$
and $j(\tau) = \frac{E_4(\tau)^3}{\Delta(\tau)}$ where $E_4(\tau)$ is the Eisenstein series for $k = 4$ and $\Delta$ is the Ramanujan Delta function. Define $f(\tau) = \frac{j(\tau)}{j(2\tau)}$.
There's 3 questions that I cannot for the life of me answer, despite spending many days on it. Firstly, we need to find the cusps of $\Gamma_1(p)$ for each prime $p$. I've spent some time on it, but generally the questions I've done I can get away with just considering the orbits of $0$ and $\infty$, so I'm a little confused at where to go from here.
Secondly, we need to show $f$ is a modular function of weight $0$ and level $\Gamma_1(2)$. I think I'm quite confused by this as I don't really understand how to work with the $j(2\tau)$ part of the function, I don't know if this is me being silly though.
Lastly, and I am completely lost here, we need to find which cusps $f(\tau)$ is holomorphic at. This is hard as I don't know the cusps, but even if I did I'd really struggle with showing holomorphicity like this.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!
EDIT: I think I have my second question? The question is to prove that $\frac{j(\tau)|_0[\gamma]}{j(2\tau)|_0[\gamma]} = \frac{j(\tau)}{j(2\tau)}$ for any $\gamma \in \Gamma_1(2)$, which because $\gamma \in \Gamma_1(2) \subseteq \Gamma(1)$ we know $j(\tau)|_0[\gamma] = j(\tau)$, so the question reduces to showing $j(2\tau)|_0[\gamma] = j(2\tau)$. We see
\begin{align*}
j(2\tau)|_0[\gamma] &= j(\tau)|_0\left[ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right]|_0[\gamma] \\
&= j(\tau)|_0\left[ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \gamma \right] \\
&= j(\tau)|_0\left[\gamma \gamma^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \gamma \right] \\
&= j(\tau)|_0\left[\gamma^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \gamma \right] \\
&= j(\tau)|_0\left[\gamma^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \gamma \right]
\end{align*}
so we are done if $\gamma^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \gamma = \beta \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for some $\beta \in \Gamma(1)$, or in other words if $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \gamma \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma(1)$ (as $\gamma^{-1} \in \Gamma(1)$). If $\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$, then
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \gamma \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & 2b \\ \frac{c}{2} & d \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma(1)$$ as $c \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

Hint: $\Gamma_1(2)$ and $\Gamma_0(2)$ are in fact two different names for the same group. (This is specific to p = 2 of course, in general $\Gamma_1(p)$ has index $p - 1$ in $\Gamma_0(p)$.)

Ah, I didn't realise the simplification! So the cusps of $\Gamma_1(2)$ then are $0, \infty$ right? So would we try and use $q$-expansions to compute $f(\tau)j(2\tau) = j(\tau)$ to finish this? So I know $j(\tau)$ has a simple pole at $\infty$, so $j(\tau) = a_{-1}q^{-1} + \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n q^n$, so $j(2\tau) = a_{-1}q^{-2} + \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n q^{2n}$, which I think implies $f(\tau)$ is of the form $\sum_{n \geq 1} b_n q^n$, so is holomorphic at $\infty$. Then for $0$, considering $f|_0\left[ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right]$ we do a similar argument for the cusp $0$?

Would you have any hints about how to find $\Gamma_1(p)$ for odd primes $p$? I've found https://dms.umontreal.ca/~mlalin/mat6684w/hwk3modular-sol.pdf online but there's no motivation given for this, the cusps come out of nowhere!

What is the relation between  $,j(\tau),$ and $,j(-\frac1{\tau})$ and then $,f(\tau),$ and $,f(-\frac1{2\tau}),$?
